# Kendo UI window making server control to loose values

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui, telerik, postback

I'm using [Kedo UI Window](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window) in my aspx page, like shown below.
Server control inside window is loosing it's value after postback. I know Kendo is a client side library & is not responsible for state management of my server side controls but why is it causing them to loose their value???

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test3.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test3" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server" id="form1">
        <div id="dialog">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TxtIn" />
        </div>

        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TxtOut" />

        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Btn" Text="Submit" />
    </form>
    <script>
        $("#dialog").kendoWindow({
            actions: ["Minimize", "Maximize"]
        });
        $("#dialog").data("kendoWindow").center();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In Snippet above on click of **Btn** postback happens after which **TxtOut** retains it's value but **TxtIn** looses it, why is not clear to me. I believe it's something to do with the DOM changes that Kendo window does, not sure but. Can someone explain please, and provide any work around...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you convert any div element into Kendo-Window at that time it remove the div from form tag and it create new div and add your existing div in it.

Please check below screenshot for more detail.

[image]

Please check the behavior of below code snippet you will get idea why the 'TxtIn' textbox not retains its value after postback.

```
<body>
    <form runat="server" id="form1">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TxtOut" />

        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Btn" Text="Submit" />
    </form>
    <input type="text" id="TxtIn" /> 
</body>
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: ahh!! right... Is there any work around for this? May be using some other popups providing plugins instead of Kendo UI ? Do u have any idea ?

Comment: I have knowledge of only two Javascript/Jquery plugins (Kendo-UI,Jquery-UI) and there behavior is also same.  We have to manually store and retrive the textbox value from/in hiddenfield/cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I found it! Kendo provides an elegant solution to this problem. It's a configuration [appendTo](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#configuration-appendTo). Using it you can define under which element of your DOM the window should append. By default it must be body hence it was appending at it "after form tag", just changed it to my form to make it append to my form element instead, and it's working great now.

```
$("#dialog").kendoWindow({
  actions: ["Minimize", "Maximize"],
  appendTo: "form#form1" // This one does the magic
});
```